# Bose QC 25 Headphone Cable Type

Tags: audio, headphones

I am trying to repair my set of Bose QC25s and I need to buy more cable in order to do so. I am not sure which type I need specifically. The cable looks like this:[image]

It appears to have 4 conductors, 3 of which are coated in enamel insulation and 1 that is bare copper. The diameter of the outer insulation is 2mm, while the inner conductors are ~0.5mm in diameter.

My searches on electronic suppliers with these parameters have not been successful.

If you know what type of cable this is, I would be very happy to know!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, your question appears like a repair based question. Change your question such that it should appear more like a part identification based question as repair questions are off-topic here.

Comment: that may be special highly flexible cable ..... the photo that you posted is not very good (should be covering only 6 squares, not 50) ...... the individual conductors probably consist of a bundle of non-conductive fiber with wire wound around the outside of the bundle ..... these are a pain to solder properly .......... google `ultraflexible miniature cables`

Comment: maybe you can install a headphone jack into the headphones and then use a patch cable to connect the headphones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A lot of audio devices use these kinds of wire.
- These wires are simply known as *Enamel Wire / Magnet Wire*.
- In your case it is a 4-pole enamel wire (see [this](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/4-Pole-Stereo-Cable-3-5mm_60325484593.html)).
- Also, take a look at [this](https://hackaday.com/2016/11/22/iron-tips-soldering-headphones-and-enamel-wire/) hackaday post.